# TypeError('JwtStrategy requires a secret or key')

Tags: node.js, jwt

Hey everyone i am using passport.js and there in secretOrKey if assign value through process.env.SECRET_KEY it's shows the mentioned error.

```
throw new TypeError('JwtStrategy requires a secret or key');
        ^

TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key
```

passport.js

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

const User = require('../models/user');
require('dotenv').config();

const opts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET
};

module.exports = passport => {
    passport.use(
        new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
            User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
                .then(user => {
                    if (user) return done(null, user);
                    return done(null, false);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    return done(err, false, {message: 'Server Error'});
                });
        })
    );
};
```

.env
[image: .env file all keys]
Already write `require("dotenv").config({path: '../.env'});` on top of the file.

But If i assign a value like `secretOrkey: "secret"` it resolve the `TypeError('JwtStrategy requires a secret or key')` this error.
When logging in by using postman and send a request then it shows `"message": "secretOrPrivateKey must have a value"` i don't know what i am missing.

Comment: You are using the default path of `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`, is that right?  You also write that you want `config({path: '../.env'})`.

Comment: dotenv also recommends that you run it with preloading, you might want to use that approach.

Comment: Please can you explain more ?? I am not getting your point.

Comment: Your process.env.JWT_SECRET is not defined because you are not using dotenv correctly. All the information I got was from the npm page of dotenv.

Comment: Yeah i also read the documentation again and i fix that issue. Thanks Man!